# PhoneGap application built with "PhoneGap Build" submission to App Store

Tags: ios, cordova, app-store, submission

Is it possible to generate a binary via https://build.phonegap.com/ which will be ready for submission in the App Store?

I don't want to do it through Xcode but only via "PhoneGap Build". The [FAQ](https://build.phonegap.com/faq) and [press release](http://phonegap.com/blog/2012/09/24/phonegap-build-is-launched) state that it is possible:

```
Quickly and easily get back app-store ready apps for multiple platforms, 
including: *Apple iOS*, Google Android, ...
```

So, I have successfuly built and tested my app on both android and ios. In addition I have successfuly built a release ready version for android store (google play) and submitted.

My problem is that I cannot seem to be able to do the same for App Store. While trying to submit with the Application Loader I get:

```
Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, 
contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone 
Distribution Certificate

Unable to extract entitlements from application:
/var/folders/vr/ghc8p.../T/APPNAME.ipa/Payload/APPNAME.app/APPNAME
```

Note that I did use the distribution certificates for building the .ipa from PhoneGap Build

Any idea where I should look next?

Comment: Have you tried regenerating your certs from Apple?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that it was a PhoneGap Build bug. The old certificates seem to have been cached. I deleted the application (in PhoneGap Build) and all my certificate configurations. I created a new application and a new certificate configuration with the last good distribution certificates that I had previously used when I posted the question.

The build was successfuly accepted from the Application Loader.

So this was a PhoneGap Build bug.